# Dash python : How to fill dcc.dropdown with csv content?

Tags: python, dropdown, plotly-dash

I would like to create an web app in python and Dash. The first that I try is to create a dropdown.

I've these data :

```
Date,FS,Total,Used,Mount
2020-01-25-12-00,/dev/hd1/,350,300,/dev/mount1
2020-01-25-18-00,/dev/hd2/,370,320,/dev/mount2
2020-01-26-06-00,/dev/hd3/,395,350,/dev/mount3
2020-01-26-12-00,/dev/hd1/,350,300,/dev/mount1
2020-01-26-18-00,/dev/hd2/,370,320,/dev/mount2
2020-01-27-06-00,/dev/hd3/,395,350,/dev/mount3
2020-01-27-12-00,/dev/hd1/,350,300,/dev/mount1
2020-01-27-18-00,/dev/hd2/,370,320,/dev/mount2
2020-01-28-06-00,/dev/hd3/,395,350,/dev/mount3
2020-01-28-12-00,/dev/hd1/,350,300,/dev/mount1
2020-01-28-18-00,/dev/hd2/,370,320,/dev/mount2
2020-01-29-06-00,/dev/hd3/,395,350,/dev/mount3
```

I would like to create a dropdown with all the FS of my CSV. I try that :

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import sys
import os
import pandas as pd 

app = dash.Dash


df = pd.read_csv('/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/data.txt')

test = df['FS'].unique()

dcc.Dropdown(
    options=[test],
    searchable=False
)  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

But the output is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./import dash.py", line 25, in <module>
    app.run_server(debug=True)
TypeError: run_server() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Can you tell me why ?

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues in your code:

1. You have to assign a name to your dash application, e.g. `app = dash.Dash('app_name')`
2. Your csv has mixed separators (`,` in header and `;` in tuples)
3. The dropdown-options syntax is `{'label: 'somelabel', 'value':'somevalue'}`, e.g. (ref. [Dropdown Examples and Reference](https://dash.plot.ly/dash-core-components/dropdown))

```
options=[
        {'label': 'New York City', 'value': 'NYC'},
        {'label': 'Montreal', 'value': 'MTL'},
        {'label': 'San Francisco', 'value': 'SF'}
    ],
```

4. You have to assign your components to `app.layout`

To sum up:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import sys
import os
import pandas as pd 


app = dash.Dash('app_name')

df = pd.read_csv('/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/data.txt')

test = df['FS'].unique()
options = [{'label': t, 'value': t} for t in test]

app.layout = dcc.Dropdown(
    options=options,
    searchable=False
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```